# How to show all repos one has access to on origin?

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to know what repos one has access to on origin? I know some tools provide this information, but i am looking for a command line solution.

Answer (score 2):

`origin`, assuming you mean the name of the remote that's crated on clone (as it's just a name, which you can change) is just the one repository.

If what you want to know is how many other repositories you have access to on the same server, then the answer depends completely on what's managing the git repositories there.

For example, gitolite will show you a list when you try to ssh into the computer, so e.g. `ssh git@host` would give you a human-readable list with the permissions your user has. More complex systems like GitHub, Gitorious etc. provide a RESTful API tools can talk to, but there is no unified way of providing this information.

Answer (score 1):

can you try : `ssh git@<ip>`

`ssh` is a command located in the folder `<git installation folder>/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'origin' is a GIT name for a remote.  You can see the actual remote using:

```
  git remote show origin
```

which will print something like:

```
ebg@ebg(64)$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://ebg@tsuki/Users/ebg/repo/kg.git
  Push  URL: ssh://ebg@tsuki/Users/ebg/repo/kg.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                             tracked
```

The URL listed tells you where the repository is located; in my case, on a machine called 'tsuki'.

So, **your question**, how many repos are on 'tsuki' that I have access to?  Generally unknowable - because a repo is just a location in the file system that I can read.  Perhaps you could try something like:

```
find / -name 'HEAD' -print
```